Recommended firebase signInWithEmail method with Deno
Using sendSignInLinkToEmail and signInWithEmailLink firebase utilities gives me 404 Error for node:process and node:buffer. (these Node.js modules not supported by Deno)
How do I implement integration with Deno?
Is the Firebase REST API the only solution?

Why are you trying to use these methods with deno?  Firebase Auth implements stateful client-side only sign-ins that support  any number of user devices.   Backends don't have the sense of state required to work this way.  The way that backends get a hold of user data is by passing an ID token from the frontend to the backend and using the Firebase Admin SDK to validate the token as described in the documentation.  Anything else is not really compatible with the way Firebase works.

"your recommended method for an optimal integration with Deno?" is subjective, so likely to get closed. If you tried to do something that you thought should work and didn't edit your question to show what you tried and where you got stuck.

As Doug commented already, the Firebase Admin SDKs for use in backend processes don't have any methods to sign a user in, while the Firebase SDKs for use in front-end processes typically won't work in many backend environments.
If there's no SDK for an environment, you can consider calling the REST API for Firebase Authentication, although I don't see any methods to send an email sign-in link there at first glance.
My recommend for this is always the same: use the Firebase client-side SDKs in your client-side application code, rather than trying to rebuild part of that functionality in your own server. If you need to know what user is using your app on the server, you can retrieve the ID token on the client, send it securely to the server, and verify it there.

Thanks.
There is the requestType: "EMAIL_SIGNIN" with the sendSignInLink() function. Let me try that then.
